# In AWS Redshift cluster i haved created a database now i want to see the database manually instead of querying it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, cluster-computing, talend

i have created a database in Redshift cluster now i want see the database and its tables manually instead of querying it.
 Where can i see those database

create database example1;

Comment: you mean like a sql workbench tool. you can here https://www.blendo.co/amazon-redshift-guide-data-analyst/import-and-export-data/tools-to-connect-to-amazon-redshift-cluster/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Redshift, there is no way to look at the data in any way except by issuing queries and commands against it. This is fairly common for most DBMS products.

AWS "recommend" the free tool Sqlworkbench/J
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-using-workbench.html

In addition you can issue commands against Redshift using the AWS management console
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/query-editor.html

My personal favorite (as a professional developer) is to use the Jetbrains DataGrip product.

Comment: I was able to see the tables under public in Redshift but i was not able to see the database under public can you please help me with that.

Comment: public is a schema, not a database. you connect to a database then you see "public" schema named. take a look at your connection string, that gives you the name of the database that you are connecting to.